# Synctex fails for input files. Related to fancyhdr + graphicx?

Tags: graphics, fancyhdr, forward-inverse-search, sublime-text

I have run into a problem with the synctex option of pdflatex that seems to be related to the fancyhdr and graphicx package.

**Problem**: Forward and inverse search between editor and PDF viewer work only for the `root.tex` and don't work for the tex file included via `\input{input.tex}`.

Fwd/Inv search does work, as soon as I remove the JPG from the header.

Here's a stripped down, short example of the problem (`root.tex`):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\rhead{\includegraphics[height = 1 cm, trim = 0cm 5cm 0cm 5cm, clip]{pic.jpg} }
}

\begin{document}

 \tableofcontents
 \pagebreak

 \chapter{main document}

 main main main

 main main main

 main main main

 \input{input.tex}

\end{document}
```

`input.tex` looks as follows:

```
\chapter{input chapter}
input input input

input input input

input input input
```

pic.jpg is a 1700x800px 110KB file in the original, but the problem also occurs for smaller files.

The PDF output looks correct. Both tex files are in the synctex file. But forwards and inverse search don't work for `input.tex` in the example above.
The problem occurs identically in both following configurations:

- Win7 x64
- Miktex
- Sublime Text 3 + LatexTools (using `texify`)
- SumatraPDF

and

- Linux Mint 17.2 x64
- TeXlive
- Sublime Text 3 + LatexTools (using `latexmk`)
- Evince

Any ideas how to fix that or where that problem might come from?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem (with example-image), and I had it once in a larger document too: In one chapter sync didn't work. As far as I can see the `clip` option is the problem. But it is unclear how exactly (in my larger document there were no images in the header, I had them in floats.). It helps to put a `\newpage` before the `\input`.

Comment: The problem seems indeed related to the `clip` option. My problem is, however, the whole thing is part of a huge project and I'm only supposed to edit the `input.tex`. In this case `\newpage` doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't know why clip confuses the synctex infos. It doesn't help to put the graphics in a box. Perhaps @HeikoOberdiek has an idea. But as a workaround you could move the content to `input-a.tex`, and write `\newpage\input{input-a}` in your current input file.

Comment: The problems is still there, even if I add a `\newpage` before the `\input` in the example above. Did that solve the problem for you?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't use exactly your example: During the tests I at first tried to store the graphic in a box and used `\rhead{\usebox{\myheaderimagebox}}`. This makes a difference.

Comment: [This thread](http://tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2009-May/008026.html) provides a MWE in tex if anyone knows how to use superpowers for good. Otherwise He also comes to a MWE in latex which is essentially the `clip` option.

Answer (score 2):

This (longstanding) bug seems to be resolved in TeXlive 2017. The maintainer has committed "a number of nontrivial changes to fix that `\pdfxform` issue".
(See https://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2017-April/040021.html)

After the last updates of my pretest installation the example compiles fine and synctex no longer fails for the input file.