# Synchronization failed between pdf and tex

Tags: forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf

I use Sumatra in my document work-flow with TeXstudio and TeXlive2015 with LuaLaTeX. Typically, a double click in the pdf sends me to the corresponding position in the tex file.

In the last chapter of my current document I get the message from Sumatra: "No synchronization info at this position". When I try to create a MWE, I figured out that commenting out some `\includegraphics` in a `center` environment solves the problem. However, it was not possible for me to create a real MWE.

Do anyone knows this problem?
Do you have a hint how to dig into or even solve it?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263105/synctex-fails-for-input-files-related-to-fancyhdr-graphicx#comment631509_263105

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike! If I got it right, I have to encapsulate all `\includegraphics` in a `\usebox` and add a `\newpage` in front of every `\include` macro?

Comment: I don't know what exactly helps. I would start with the `\newpage` -- it helped in a larger document where I had the problem too, the usebox-trick seemed to be relevant only if the graphic is in the header or footer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the hint to add a `\newpage` before every `\include` command does not solve the problem.