# "No synchronization info at this position" PARTIAL failure

Tags: forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and SumatraPDF as viewer. In my thesis (about 1000 pages) forward and backward synchronization is working fine. In my friends thesis it only works in some chapters (my and his installation) and in others not. Hence, I think it is a TeX thing.
Upon the attempt of creating a minimal example (the lazy \includeonly{} variant) the search works in all individual chapter again. Tracking this down is a little tedious -- and makes it difficult to post a minimal example.
I suspect that some command is compromising the .syntext file, but this one is tough to debug.

Did anyone encounter a similar behavior (and maybe has a hint what are good candidates to check)? Everything is reproducible with the whole project.
I do not post what I tried so far - maybe there was only a small tweak missing.

Cheers,
HJ

Comment: The clip option in includegraphics can disturb synctex: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263105/synctex-fails-for-input-files-related-to-fancyhdr-graphicx

Comment: It's heavily used! -- I'll check this. It works in my thesis but I only use it on pdfs if I remember correctly.   Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when I was using `\include` to add multiple chapters, the sync data was only available for the first chapter. Then I used `\input` and it solved the problem.

Comment: In my case it occurs with include as well as with input.
It seems to be related to the clip command.