# menukeys package breaks SyncTeX for \input files?

Tags: input, forward-inverse-search

Including the `menukeys` package breaks SyncTeX's inverse search for content included by `\input`.

MWE:

`mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{menukeys}

\begin{document}

Hello World.

\input{input.tex}

\end{document}
```

`input.tex`:

```
Bonjour Le Monde.
```

Double-clicking the Hello World on the PDF takes me to `mwe.tex`, but double-clicking Bonjour Le Monde results in a message "No synchronization info at this position". I expected it to take me to `input.tex`.

System:

- OS: Windows 10
- LaTeX compiler: TeXworks 0.6.6, using pdfLaTeX.
- PDF Viewer: SumatraPDF 3.3.3 64-bit.
- TeX Editor: Notepad++ 8.1.9.2 32-bit

(I prefer to use TeXworks for compiling the TeX only. I'm not bothered about forward search.)

I'm aware that several people have raised similar issues with SyncTeX and `\input` files, such as [Synctex fails for input files. Related to fancyhdr + graphicx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263105/synctex-fails-for-input-files-related-to-fancyhdr-graphicx). However, the most recent post says it's resolved. A `\clearpage` fixes the issue but this doesn't always result in a pleasing document.

Is there more up-to-date information on resolving this? Should I consider raising an issue, and if so, where? SyncTeX?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please include a `\listfiles` in your preamble and post the resulting log? I'll try to investigate.

Comment: @Skillmon the problem is from tikz, more exactly it breaks as soon as one add one `\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading` from pgflibraryfadings.code.tex, but I don't have the time now to look more, so if you find something ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer at least in TeXstudio everything works fine with SyncTeX. Since I'm not on Windows I can't test SumatraPDF. Still curious that it works flawlessly in both directions in TeXstudio and TeXworks on Linux.

Comment: @Skillmon, do you still want the `\listfiles` log? Also, I tried the Windows version of TeXstudio 4.1.2. Its PDF viewer does the inverse search correctly, but SumatraPDF still returns "No synchronisation info...". Do you or @UlrikeFischer think it's worth me posting a bug report with Sumatra?

Comment: No, the `\listfiles` was a stab in the dark (or to put it more precisely: `menukeys` had a major change about a year ago and I just wanted to make sure that you don't use an old version). With @UlrikeFischer's precise analysis that's no longer necessary. And yes, I'd report this to the Sumatra maintainers.

Comment: https://forum.sumatrapdfreader.org/t/synctexs-inverse-search-failing-could-sumatra-be-contributing/4669/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It breaks for me as soon as I add an immediate xform (something that the fadings libary of pgf does too):

```
\documentclass{article}

\setbox0\hbox{A}
\immediate\pdfxform0
\begin{document}

Hello World.

\input{input1.tex}

\end{document}
```

This gives a synctex file with beside other this here

```
Output:pdf
Magnification:1000
Unit:1
X Offset:0
Y Offset:0
Content:
x0,0:491521,447828 %<------ from the xform
!1346
```

Imho the marked part confuses sumatra.

I added an issue here https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex/issues/44

I have some doubts `pgf` really has to use `\immediate\pdfxform resources`, imho simply `\pdfxform resources` should work too. So another solution could be to ask pgf to change that in the relevant driver files.

Comment: What you marked does not conform to synctex specs (see man 5 synctex). These specs can change if this is an absolute requirement and that would imply a change to the synctex library as well.